# General square form of Taylor expansion polynomial

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, multinomial-theorem

Suppose we have a Taylor expansion for a function $f$ with respect to t up to $M$-th order.

$$
\begin{equation}
T_M = \sum^M_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}f^k(x)\Delta t^k = f(x) + f'(x)\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)\Delta t^2 + \cdots
\end{equation}
$$

What would be the general form of $T_M^2$ with **respect to $\Delta t$?**

$$
\begin{equation}
T_M\times T_M = (\sum^M_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}f^k(x)\Delta t^k)^2 = (???) + (???)\Delta t + (???)\Delta t^2 + \cdots
\end{equation}
$$

Perhaps [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) can help?

Comment: It's just the general form for squaring a polynomial, but you can drop higher order terms if all you want is the $M$th order approximation. Note: the $1/k!$ is inside the summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are squaring a sum we can utilize
$$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_ka_j $$
Applying this formula onto our problem yields

$$ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}f^k(x)\Delta t^k\right)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{M}\sum_{j=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{j!}f^k(x)f^j(x)\Delta t^{k+j} $$
Taking a closer look at the coefficients of $\Delta t^{k+j}$, we see that there are $k+j+1$ different combinations of $k$ and $j$. For example ($k+j=3$ cf. Jose Brox' answer), we have the combinations for:
$$ (k,j) \in \{(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0)\}$$

Thus we can rewrite the above sum
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{M}\sum_{j=0}^{M} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{j!}f^k(x)f^j(x)\Delta t^{k+j} = \sum_{k=0}^{M}\left[ \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{j!}\frac{1}{(k-j)!}f^j(x)f^{k-j}(x)\right]\Delta t^k$$
where the coefficient corresponding to the $k$-th exponent is
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{j!(k-j)!}f^j(x)f^{k-j}(x) $$

Comment: In the second last equation, is that truncated to the order $M$?

Comment: My fault, I think it should be $k$ instead of $M$ in the second sum term.

Answer (score 0):

Like with usual polynomial multiplication, the term of degree $k$ comes from adding up all products of two monomials whose degrees sum to $k$. For example, for degree $3$ you have $(0,3)+(1,2)+(2,1)+(3,0)$.