# How is the general formula for the square of a polynomial reached at in this paper?

Tags: polynomials

In the following paper in equation 104, we have the following general formula for the square of a polynomial:

https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/106948/Roy_Aggresive%20flight.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

[image]

But on this Stack Exchange answer, the square of a polynomial has a different general formula.

[General square form of Taylor expansion polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241494/general-square-form-of-taylor-expansion-polynomial)

Which ones correct?[image]

Can you explain how the convolution in the paper is reached at?

Comment: Those formulas are answering two different questions. One is about the coefficients of the square of a polynomial and one is about the square of a sum. If you set $a_k = p_k x^k$ in the second formula and collect like terms you'll get the first formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(P^2\right)_n$ denotes the coefficient on $x^n$ of $P(x)^2$. Applying the linked answer, $$P^2=\left(\sum_{k=0}^Np_kx^k\right)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^N p_kx^kp_jx^j$$

The $x^k \cdot x^j$ can be combined as $x^{k+j}$ and instead of summing over $k$ and $j$, you can sum over $n = k+j$ and $j$ to get $$\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^n \sum_{j=0}^Np_jp_{n-j}$$

The coefficient on $x^n$ is then $\sum_{j=0}^Np_jp_{n-j}$.

Comment: Should not the polynomial reach a degree $2N$ if the original one was $N$?